# I want to send the following web page request using a cronjob with raspberry pi

Tags: cron-task

can anyone point me in the right direction? 
I want to send the following webpage request using a cron job with raspberry pi,

http://10.0.1.224/socket1On

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Install `curl` using `aptitude install curl`, then `crontab -e` and...

```
0 * * * * curl http://10.0.1.224/socket1On >/dev/null
```

(This runs once on each full hour - adjust as necessary of course.)

This throws away the answer; if you need it, you can save it to some file, or course. Errors will be mailed to whatever mail account you let your mails get forwarded to, by cron.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it later :-)